# Android Libraries for easy Multi Touch implementation that includes Twist/Rotate etc?

Tags: android, multi-touch

Has anyone run across a good implementation in library or package form that implements MULTI touch processing that includes pinch-zoom, rotate, two finger swipe etc. and is relatively easy to extend?

I wrote the code for pinch-zoom and two finger swipe, but it's been awhile and I am tired of relearning this somewhat messy API with all of it's gotcha's every time I need to extend my actions.

Comment: "that implements MULTI touch processing" -- of what? An `ImageView`? A `Button`? A custom-drawn 2D image on a `View` by way of a `Canvas`? An OpenGL scene? A `WebView`? A video playing back in a `VideoView`? You can *detect* these sorts of gestures with a `GestureDetector`, and that should work for most if not all of the cases I list. *Applying* those sorts of gestures, though, will vary widely, and the implementations are going to be very different for each of the scenarios I mentioned.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have looked at the gesture detector, seems buggy, or I don't get how to use it properly. I am looking at rotation on a Google Map View today, but also OpenGL in a bit. This looks promising but I will have to look closer http://paulbourke.blogspot.com/2011/10/writing-multitouch-applications-on.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can find at this point is

[Howto use - Multi Touch Controller](http://paulbourke.blogspot.com/2011/10/writing-multitouch-applications-on.html) from Luke Hutchison's [source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/)

If anyone else has something better please post!