# Touchscreen gestures list and names

Tags: android, c++, ios, ipad, gesture

Where can I find a list of all (many) touchscreen gestures including complex 4 and 5 finger ones for iPad, with a reasonable technical implementation guidelines and code (C++/Java) examples?

Comment: iPad I have no idea, for Android anything other than basic (trivial) examples don't really exist.  I suggest you break this out into separate android and an iOS questions to get better results.

Comment: I just want to find a reasonable list to implement them. GestureDetector in Android is quite trivial. 3/4/5 fingers gestures exist but i cannot find any reasonable implementation details.

Comment: Again, I have looked and not found much in the way of how-to, if you just want a "Standardized" list of potential gestures to implement then maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch as a general list.  Beyond 2 fingers I don't think there is anything standard.

Comment: Here is my answer to myself on how-to simplify this on Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454570/android-libraries-for-easy-multi-touch-implementation-that-includes-twist-rotate

Comment: To my understanding, these 4 and 5 finger iPad gestures are like "meta" gestures, they switch between apps and stuff... so you shouldn't need to implement them in an app, that would be like having your desktop app have a special behavior for alt-tab or something. My pet theory is that Apple is secretly in bed with doctors that treat carpal tunnel syndrome. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FqU7JHWlGI

Comment: Basic iOS http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html - if you are asking for associative gestures I don't know of any on Android, and for iOS I think they are all pretty much built in

Comment: Wikipedia is a good starting point for simple gestures, but still no 4/5 finger ones. I want to implement them on Android.

Comment: I believe the search for Apple's patents would do a better job than reading Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These links may be useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27354/Implementing-Mouse-Gestures-in-Java-Swing-Step-by

http://www.igesture.org/impl_gesturerepresentation.html

http://britg.com/2011/05/14/complex-gesture-recognition-in-ios-part-1-the-research

Picture with gestures: http://graffletopia.com/stencils/432

Apple's reference with descriptions and videos: http://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/gestures.html

Dan Rodney's list of MacOS X multi-touch gestures: http://www.danrodney.com/mac/multitouch.html

Answer (score 17):

After two days of search i have found these links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch#Multi-touch_gestures - simple gestures

http://blogs.computerworld.com/18672/the_lion_multitouch_gesture_guide - more complex multi-finger gestures on Apple devices

[http://medialoot.com/item/40-vector-multitouch-gestures](http://medialoot.com/item/40-vector-multitouch-gestures/) - 40 multitouch gestures

Unfortunately, nothing usable was found in the Apple's patents regarding gestures.

Comment: Take a look at here also: http://medialoot.com/item/40-vector-multitouch-gestures/

Comment: Added your link to the answer

Comment: and here: http://gestureworks.com/features/open-source-gestures/?utm_source=iOS+Dev+Weekly&utm_campaign=082750a043-iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_51&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 3):

Though this might not help, you can take a look at this:
[Gesture Coder: A Tool for Programming Multi-Touch 
Gestures by Demonstration](http://yangl.org/pdf/gcoder.pdf)

There's a tutorial that concatenating those articles from iOS developer guide: [An iPhone iOS 5 Gesture Recognition Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_5_Gesture_Recognition_Tutorial)

---

These are the related articles in the iOS Developer Library.

- [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1):

  - [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279)

    - [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer)
    - [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    - [UIRotationGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIRotationGestureRecognizer)
    - [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    - [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    - [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Well, that is not exactly what i asked for, but worth mentioning.